# Text at the end of the page

Tags: positioning

I would create a page with some text at the end of the page. Initially the page is blank and after I add text using:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\stretch{5}}
    \begin{center}
        Text
    \end{center}
```

The content should be add at the end. Could be right the solution I proposed?

Comment: Yes, it's good. But `\stretch{1}` (equivalent to `\fill`) is enough. Using `\stretch` with different values is helpful when there's more than one on the page (when you want to position a dedication, for instance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
        Text
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\begin{center}
        Text
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```